# How much does people's moods matter?

Tags: spiritfarer

The various people on my ship have a mood indicator and I can make them happier by feeding them foods they like and giving them hugs.

What effects does mood have? I haven't really been able to determine why I would need to keep people in a good mood, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When spirts are in a good mood they will perform various tasks around your ship such as helping your plants grow or giving you fish and valuables.